# Syntax highlighting in org mode #+BEGIN_LATEX block

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Is this possible?  (I know it's possible for `#+BEGIN_SRC latex` blocks.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems to be possible, by specifying `latex` as an extra parameter to the LaTeX fragment (!), as if it were a `src` block.

```
#+BEGIN_LaTeX latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (1,1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
#+END_LaTeX
```

To compare:

[image: screenshot]

(from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/57whx0/how_to_fontify_begin_latex_blocks_natively/))

I'm not sure the behavior is intentional, but it seems to be working great.

Comment: I don't care if this is intentional or not, it's incredible helpful, thank you @VanLaser!

Comment: I call it a beginner's luck, looking through Org mode source code :P What I can't understand is how this behavior wasn't already stumbled upon, even by mistake (it seems easy enough to (mis)type).

Comment: Great find. Though even though it works I guess it's quite sloppy engineering and it'd be much better to fix the behavior and let it highlight LaTeX automatically. Currently if you write any other language name it will highlight using that language as well...

Comment: The links in the question are broken - can you please add code to show what to do.

Comment: @AndrewSwann You just need to use `#+BEGIN_LaTeX latex` instead of `#+BEGIN_LaTeX`.

Comment: That is what I understood.  My request is that you update your answer so that it is readable without relying on external links and any external links included are functional.

Comment: Both links work for me.

Comment: The links may work for you, but the point is to make the content available to your readers… Please don't rely on external links in your answer. Use the image tool to include images rather than linking to external images, that uploads the image to a service that partners with Stack Exchange (images on imgur ordinarily expire after a while, but not those on the SE/imgur partner site).

Comment: Thanks for the edit. When volunteering my free time, I usually don't try to solve non-problems, especially when requested and there's not an *actual* need.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that for the current version of Org Mode that I am using (Org mode 9.1.9), that the command has changed to `#+BEGIN_EXPORT latex` and `#+END_EXPORT latex`.  See https://orgmode.org/manual/Quoting-LaTeX-code.html#Quoting-LaTeX-code for details.

Comment: Also use `<l` and then press tab to use Org mode structural templates to fill it in for you: https://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-Templates.html#Structure-Templates